# Hiding the interface of an extended class in dart

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a validation layer that wraps calls to business logic methods in entities in the domain layer.

A Validator must have the same interface as the Entity and give access to the state the Entity holds.

However, the type signatures of the Validator's interface methods need to different to the Entity's, as the Validator may validate and convert inputs from the UI (for example). The Validator also needs wraps these input validation/conversions calls and the underlying business logic method call in try catches.

This is an example of my current implementation:

```
class Entity {
  // state
  int _num;
  int get num => _num;

  // init the state
  Entity(this._num = 0)

  // business logic methods
  void incrementBy(int n) {
    // business logic validation
    if (n <= 0){
      throw Exception('[n] must be greater than 0'); // shouldn't throw raw Exceptions in general
    }
    // business logic
    _num += n;
  }
}

class Validator {
  // have to hold an instance of the entity
  final Entity _entity;

  Validator(this._entity);

  // have to copy the getters in the entity class
  int get num => _entity.num;

  // same interface as the Entity, but different type signature
  void incrementBy(String n) {
    try {
      // validate user input
      final inc = ConvertToInt(n); // -> could throw a FormatException
      // call the underlying busines logic
      _entity.incrementBy(inc); // -> could throw an Exception
    } on Exception catch (e) { // shouldn't catch raw Exceptions in general
      ...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to wrap the entity?

It feels very clunky to do it the way shown above because there is no enforcement of which methods need to be overridden, as would be the case of `implementing` the Entity, which you can't do as the type signatures must be the same.

Something like `class Validator hides Entity{...}` would be great. It would be something like the combination of an `extends`, you wouldn't need to hold an instance of the entity or reimplement the getters, and an `implements` as you would be forced to override all interface methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is worth it but you might use the `covariant` keyword and an extra interface to achieve something similar to this. It requires an extra interface and I don't exactly know if the code is less clunky but here we go.

**Edit:** Just wanted to point out that you can also place the `covariant` keyword on the interface, basically allowing any subclass of `EntityIf` to tighten the type.

[Here's the Dart Pad link to the code below](https://dartpad.dev/17e0c26fcd21ea063bbfc57292883ca7)

```dart
/// This is the common interface between the entity
/// and the validator for the entity. Both need to
/// implement this.
abstract class EntityIf {

  // Private factory constructor to disallow
  // extending this class
  EntityIf._();

  // We use 'dynamic' as the type for [num].
  // We'll enforce type later using the
  // 'covariant' keyword
  dynamic get num;

  // Same here, type is dynamic
  void incrementBy(dynamic value);
}

class Entity implements EntityIf {
  Entity(this._num);

  int _num;

  // Getters don't need the covariant keyword for some reason ?!? I'm not complaining!
  @override
  int get num => _num;

  // Here we see the covariant keyword in action.
  // It allows restricting to a more specific type
  // which is normally disallowed for overriding methods.
  @override
  void incrementBy(covariant int value) {
    _num += value;
  }
}

class ValidatorForEntity implements EntityIf {
  // Validator still needs to wrap the entity, coudln't
  // figure out a way around that
  ValidatorForEntity(this._entity)
    : assert(_entity != null);

  final Entity _entity;

  @override
  dynamic get num => _entity.num;

  // Validator just overrides the interface with no
  // covariant keyword.
  @override
  void incrementBy(dynamic value) {
    assert(value != null);

    int finalValue = int.tryParse(value.toString());
    if (finalValue == null) {
      throw '[value] is not an instance of [int]';
    }

    // int type will be enforced here, so you can't
    // create validators that break the entity
    _entity.incrementBy(finalValue);
  }
}

void main() {
  final x = ValidatorForEntity(Entity(0));

  x.incrementBy(1);
  print(x.num); // prints 1

  x.incrementBy('1');
  print(x.num); // prints 2

  try {
    x.incrementBy('a');
  } catch (e) {
    print('$e'); // should give this error
  }
}
```